# Finding Most Common Word In A Tally/Ledger System

Tags: arrays, excel, formula, mode

I currently use the following array formula to find the most common word or number in a range, ignoring any blank cells:

```
{=(INDEX(D1:D10,MODE(IF((D1:D10<>"")*ISNA(MATCH(D1:D10,$A$1:$A1,0)),MATCH(D1:D10,D1:D10,0)))))}
```

I am now looking to do something slightly different. I still want to find the most common word or number in a range, however I now have 2 lists: the first is a list of 'positive' words/numbers and the second is a list of 'negative' words/numbers.

To illustrate using an example: the colour green appears in the 'positive' list 4 times and the colour blue appears twice in the 'positive list', but green appears 3 times in the 'negative' list and blue does not appear at all in the 'negative' list. Using the above formula on the first list would return green as the most common word. However I now want it to take into account that green is not the most common word given the combined lists (i.e. 4 positives - 3 negatives = 1 green, and 2 positives - 0 negatives = 2 blue).

In the below image, using the formula under each list shows green to be the most common word. I would like to combine these lists and cancel out any instances where the colour appears on both instances - so 3 of the greens on the positive list would be cancelled out with the 3 greens on the negative list, leaving only one left.

In essence, I suppose I am trying to create a tally or ledger of some kind where rather than numbers that add or subtract I have words whose *frequency* is added or subtracted.

[image]

Thanks for the help, and apologies if I haven't been too clear in the task!

Comment: I think posting a small dataset together with your expected results would help clarify what you are asking.

Comment: I've added a screenshot and some more description...

Comment: Thanks, but actually I was hoping for you to include your expected results based on these new criteria.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but I would have a cell that returns the result of 'blue' in the above example - taking both lists together and cancelling instances that appear on both lists means that blue is the most common word left.

Comment: I see what you mean now. Is it ever possible that a given colour has more entries in the Negative column than in the Positive?

Comment: Yes, in which case I would expect to have a negative score overall for that option and thus it most definitely will not be the most common result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT((MMULT(COUNTIF(OFFSET(B2:B11,,{0,1}),B2:B11),{1;-1})=MAX(MMULT(COUNTIF(OFFSET(B2:B11,,{0,1}),B2:B11),{1;-1})))/COUNTIF(B2:B11,B2:B11&""))>1,"No Favourite",INDEX(B2:B11,MATCH(MAX(MMULT(COUNTIF(OFFSET(B2:B11,,{0,1}),B2:B11),{1;-1})),MMULT(COUNTIF(OFFSET(B2:B11,,{0,1}),B2:B11),{1;-1}),0)))
```

And for non-contiguous, dynamically-defined ranges, assumed to be stored as Defined Names Positive and Negative, **array formula****:

```
=IF(SUM((COUNTIF(Positive,Positive)-COUNTIF(Negative,Positive)=MAX(COUNTIF(Positive,Positive)-COUNTIF(Negative,Positive)))/COUNTIF(Positive,Positive&""))>1,"No Favourite",INDEX(Positive,MATCH(MAX(COUNTIF(Positive,Positive)-COUNTIF(Negative,Positive)),COUNTIF(Positive,Positive)-COUNTIF(Negative,Positive),0)))
```

Regards

***Array formulas are not entered in the same way as 'standard' formulas. Instead of pressing just ENTER, you first hold down CTRL and SHIFT, and only then press ENTER. If you've done it correctly, you'll notice Excel puts curly brackets {} around the formula (though do not attempt to manually insert these yourself).*

Comment: This works brilliantly - thanks! One question though - can I amend it in any way that it remains blank or returns 'No Favourite' if there is no clear majority (i.e. if after netting the columns, blue and green would have the same frequency)?

Comment: Updated as requested.

Comment: One more question, if I may: if the 2 lists (i.e. negative list and positive list) are on different worksheets and not side by side as in the example I gave, how do I factor this in?

Comment: =IF(SUMPRODUCT((MMULT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"Positive","Negative"}),Positive),{1;-1})=MAX(MMULT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"Positive","Negative"}),Positive),{1;-1})))/COUNTIF(Positive,Positive&""))>1,"No Favourite",INDEX(Positive,MATCH(MAX(MMULT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"Positive","Negative"}),Positive),{1;-1})),MMULT(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"Positive","Negative"}),Positive),{1;-1}),0))) where you should either define each of your ranges using Name Manager as such, or else replace all occurrences of Positive and Negative in the above appropriately. Note that this will fail if these ranges are defined dynamically.

Comment: Unfortunately my ranges are dynamically defined. I am aware that such ranges don't work well with the INDIRECT function - is there any other way to construct this amazing formula with dynamic named ranges?

Comment: Should've guessed! :-) I'm sure I can do that, though unfortunately I have to go out now so it won't be until later.

Comment: Thanks - I would really appreciate if you could help me out later! Enjoy whatever you are doing ;)

Comment: I think you need to do it the long way round. Have added a version to the post for non-contiguous ranges.

Answer (score 2):

First list your candidates in column **D** starting at **D2**

Then in **E2** enter:

```
=COUNTIF(B$2:B$12,D2)-COUNTIF(C$2:C$12,D2)
```

and copy down.

Finally in **F2** enter:

```
=INDEX(D:D,MATCH(MAX(E:E),E:E,0))
```

With your data:

[image: demo]

Comment: Thanks for this, although this issue is that I have only used an example - my full dataset contains 250+ of such 'positive' and 'negative' lists, and each of these have different data (i.e. the actual options in each of these 250+ lists is in the thousands). Is there a different way to solve this that would work better with the dataset?

Comment: I do not understand your complete data structure.

Comment: This technique should work for each pair of *Positive/Negative* columns.

Comment: In essence, I have a questionnaire of 250+ questions. The answer options differ from question to question. So a question may be 'Favourite Colour vs Most Disliked Colour', another may be 'Favourite City vs Most Disliked City' etc, each of which has obviously different answers. Using the COUNTIF solution would be time consuming given the number of options in the dataset (e.g. blue, brown, green, London, NY, Moscow as well as other colours/cities and other questions etc). Is that any clearer?

Comment: It would work for each pair of columns, the challenge is that the 'Candidate' for each question is very different and given the number of questions and candidates, the workbook would quickly become hard to manage.

Comment: **Would you consider a macro-based solution??**

Comment: Yes, provided I can run the macro from within a UserForm (which I haven't done before, but don't envisage it to be hard to implement).

Comment: Tomorrow I will update this post.....you will tell the macro which two columns to use and it will tell you the most net-positive item